# Best way to implement android library billing in BB10

Tags: android, reporting-services, blackberry-10, in-app-billing

I want to integrate in-app billing in  my Black berry 10 app that ported from android.Please suggest the correct way to do this.

Comment: Why guys downvoting and wanna close this question?? This is really helpful question for future..

Answer (score 0):

> The Google Play services is not supported on BlackBerry 10. If your
>   app uses In-app Billing version 3 API, you need to configure your
>   project to use In-app Billing version 2 or lower API.

[Check this](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/apisupport_inapp_payments_support.html) for more information about

[Features and Unsupported APIs](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/)